# Apache 2.4 Proxy Css and Js path

Tags: apache-2.4, path

I got Apache Web Server 2.4, and a JBoss 7 exposing a web project.

Since I'm working locally I made an `/etc/hosts/` domain entry like:

```
127.0.0.1    testmask
```

And put this virtual host config inside my Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>   
    ServerName testmask/
    ServerAlias  testmask
    RewriteEngine  on 
    RewriteRule   ^/$  http://testmask/MyWebapp/  [R] 
    ProxyPass / http://testmask:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://testmask:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

And this works like a charm.
If I put on browser:

```
testmask/
```

It redirects to:

```
http://testmask/MyWebapp/
```

So ok so far.

Now since I would like to have the same result but leaving only:

```
http://testmask/
```

I've made a proxy on rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule   ^/$  http://testmask/MyWebapp/  [P]
```

But I got a 404 not found problem on css and js that are relative to context root.

This is because my browser is trying to get css and js from:

```
http://testmask/static/
|-  css/*
|-  js/*
|-  medias/*
```

while they are in:

```
http://testmask/MyWebapp/static/
|-  css/*
|-  js/*
|-  medias/*
```

(typical folder structure of build\ReactJS create-react-app).

Tried different approaches via RewriteRules or Proxypass but nothing works, probably due to my poor experience on Apache.

Consider I prefer not to touch the `index.html` since my projects need to live alone also, since I'm developing it via `npm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try with mod_proxy.

First enable:

```
a2enmod mod_proxy
a2enmod mod_proxy_http
```

Then in your apache config it would look like this:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost/MyWebapp
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/MyWebapp
```

So now if you connect to http://localhost/ (or in your case http://testmask/) it should be proxy to MyWebapp.

Comment: Could you please take a look here too: https://serverfault.com/questions/900289/base-url-from-apache-2-4-reverse-proxy